# How should I encrypt data to send in URL

Tags: c#, encryption

I need to encrypt a string which I am sending in a URL and later I need to decrypt it ...

Which approach would be better for this? I tried the following:

```
string s = "String to be encrypted";

string encrypted = CipherUtility.Encrypt<RijndaelManaged>(s, "pass", "salt");

string decrypted = CipherUtility.Decrypt<RijndaelManaged>(encrypted, "pass", "salt");
```

But the encrypted string gets an "=" at the end ... I would like to avoid that.

And I am not sure that this would be the best option ...

The CipherUtility is the following:

```
public class CipherUtility
{
  public static string Encrypt<T>(string value, string password, string salt)
    where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
  {
    DeriveBytes rgb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt));

    SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = new T();

    byte[] rgbKey = rgb.GetBytes(algorithm.KeySize >> 3);
    byte[] rgbIV = rgb.GetBytes(algorithm.BlockSize >> 3);

    ICryptoTransform transform = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(rgbKey, rgbIV);

    using (MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream())
    {
       using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(buffer, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
       {
          using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.Unicode))
          {
             writer.Write(value);
          }
       }

       return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer.ToArray());
    }
 }

 public static string Decrypt<T>(string text, string password, string salt)
  where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
 {
   DeriveBytes rgb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt));

   SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = new T();

   byte[] rgbKey = rgb.GetBytes(algorithm.KeySize >> 3);
   byte[] rgbIV = rgb.GetBytes(algorithm.BlockSize >> 3);

   ICryptoTransform transform = algorithm.CreateDecryptor(rgbKey, rgbIV);

   using (MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(text)))
   {
     using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(buffer, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
     {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Unicode))
        {
           return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: after encrypting the string, can you try url encoding it?

Comment: You should use HTTPS instead of it.

Comment: Well, I was trying to get something that I would need to URL encode and get all the % in there.

Comment: Why HTTPS? In this case the data is only an email ... I need to create a URL in a newsletter to unsubscribe but I would like to not display the email raw in it

Comment: @MDMoura Instead of encrypting the URL, consider a more traditional nonce.

Comment: On a newsletter I received I see something like /unsubscribe?u=16b832d9ad4b28edf261f56df. I was looking for something like this with the email somehow "hidden" ...

Comment: @user2864740 what do you mean? I am not encrypting the url only one of the parameters: the email of the user I want to unsubscribe.

Answer (score 2):

> On a newsletter I received I see something like /unsubscribe?u=16b832d9ad4b28edf261f56df. I was looking for something like this with the email somehow "hidden"

This is not "hidden."  All this is a reference to a repository (e.g. a database) that contains all the information necessary to unsubscribe.  Essentially a key into a record that contains all the necessary info about a subscriber.

If feasible, that'll probably be easier approach than to encrypt individual values in a URL.

If you still want to encrypt the value (to avoid storage in DB and redesign), what's the issue with having `=` at the end of a URL?  It's just a character as part of encrypted output?

Comment: Yes, but in this case I am working with two system through and API and one system does not have the key of the user so I am sending the email ... My idea would be to create such a key from the email without the = at the end. I was just wondering if this was possible

Comment: But what is the issue with having = at the end?